# How to stop a test after finding specific word in jmeter response?

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, response

How can we stop a jmeter test after finding a specific word from json response:

```html
{"code":12345,"data":{"mylist":[{"myid":111,"secId":2,"TypeId":1,"name":"one two three" ,"description":"thats the value"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter)
2. Use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${value}" != "thats the value",)}
   ```
3. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as the child of the request and configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: `value`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.data.mylist[0].description`
4. That's it, the While Controller will loop until "description" fields becomes `thats the value`

Demo:

[image]